# What is a "non-UK resident" for the purpose of paying SDLT?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, stamp-duty

It is stated here: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/stamp-duty-land-tax-buying-an-additional-residential-property#sdlt-rates-for-non-uk-residents that

---

There is a 2% surcharge on residential properties in England and Northern Ireland bought by non-UK residents on or after 1 April 2021. The 2% surcharge applies on top of all other residential rates of SDLT including the higher rates for additional dwellings.

---

Unfortunately, I was not able to find the definition of *non-UK resident* on this website. Where can I find this definition? For example, suppose a person lives in the UK for the last 4 years, and spends nor more than 2 months per year outside of the UK. Will such a person be classified as a UK resident for the purpose of SDLT? (the person doesn't have a UK passport if this matters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the page you link to, clicking on the "rate for non-UK residents" link gets you to a page with a section "[SDLT residence tests](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/rates-of-stamp-duty-land-tax-for-non-uk-residents#sdlt-residence-tests)".

> Individual buyers are non-UK resident in relation to the transaction if they are not present in the UK for at least 183 days during the 12 months before their purchase.

Comment: Huge thanks! I don't think that the page you cite is the same as that I cite (at least there is not word "test" in the page I cite :) ). But it doesn't matter, indeed, this fully answers my question. Thanks again!